# how to display more information from a structure when sorting the data from an interger within

Tags: c++

```
// C++a2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
```

Ive sussed out how to display the largest interger(from .iSold) but I need it to also display the name of the stock item(from .sName and its price (from.fPrice) from the items/varibles that i have stored in the struct stock?

```
struct Stock
{
 string sName = "";
 float fPrice = 0;
 int iSold = 0;

};

int main()
{
     int iBestSeller = 0;
     cout << "Hello, welcome to the program";

     Stock stockRecords[5];

     cout << "Please enter stock name, followed by price, and amount sold: \n";

     for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {

         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName;
         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice;
         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;


    }

     for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {
     if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller)
    {
         iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
    }
     cout << "biggest seller= " << iBestSeller;//need to display the other information along with the best selling item, its name and price
}





    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please somebody help, been racking my brain for hours over this!

Comment: why not get the values in two more variables and use two more `cout` statements? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Gorans code throws up errors, it works if i nest it inside my loops(which looks all kinds of   wrong) and repeats the output 5times!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Stock iBestSeller{};
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {
    if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller.iSold) {
        iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
    }
}
cout << "biggest seller= " << iBestSeller.sName << " "
     << iBestSeller.fPrice << " " << iBestSeller.iSold << endl;
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Stock {
    string sName = "";
    float fPrice = 0;
    int iSold = 0;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, welcome to the program";

    //* <- remove first '/' from here to enable user input
    istringstream cin(
        "Stock1 10 15 \n"
        "Stock2 12  7 \n"
        "Stock3 13 17 \n"
        "Stock4 11  5 \n"
        "Stock5  3  7 \n"
    );
    // */
    Stock stockRecords[5];
    cout << "Please enter stock name, followed by price, and amount sold: \n";

    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {
        cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName
            >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice
            >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
    }

    Stock iBestSeller{};
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {
        if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller.iSold) {
            iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
        }
    }
    cout << "biggest seller= " << iBestSeller.sName << " "
         << iBestSeller.fPrice << " " << iBestSeller.iSold << endl;
}
```

Prints out:

```
Hello, welcome to the programPlease enter stock name, followed by price, and amount sold: 
biggest seller= Stock3 13 17
```

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/SJIDo93oz

Comment: thanks it kind of works, just displays the info 5 times on 5 different lines, i'll play around with it , i may have put it in the wrong place or something, thanks dude!

Comment: it throws up errors when I use your code in place of mine Goran, it actually works if i nest it inside my for loop and comment out my cout line (but that looks odd and must be wrong) but it repeats the output 5 times on 5 seperate lines!

Comment: Works fine for me, you have to remove your initial definition of `iBestSeller`. I've updated my answer to contain the complete code.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me Goran, Ive put my finished program on here( quite proud of it)!!

Answer (score 0):

So a few things... You are printing out the result 5 times because it is in your loop:

```
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {//loop start
     if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller)
    {
         iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
    }
     cout << "biggest seller= " << iBestSeller;
} //loop end
```

Your input is super difficult to follow when inputting data. Add cout statements into the input loop:

```
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
{
    cout << "Please enter stock name: ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName;
    cout << "Please enter the price for " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice;
    cout << "Please the amount sold of " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
}
```

This input style is not very robust.  Relying on `cin` for integer input is going to get you in trouble.  Any non-integer input will produce unpredictable results.  You should be taking in all data as strings and converting to integers.  [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/) is a useful link for ways to do it.

Here, I have taken Goran's suggestion and incorporated into your code.  He was simply saying best seller should be of type Stock and set it equal to which ever structure had the greatest iSold. Also, I built this in Linux, so I commented out all your Windows stuff:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Stock
{
    string sName = "";
    float fPrice = 0;
    int iSold = 0;
};

int main()
{
    //using a Stock type instead of int
    Stock iBestSeller{};

    cout << "Hello, welcome to the program\n";

    Stock stockRecords[5];

    //loop here for the input of 5 records
     for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter stock name: ";
         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName;
        cout << "Please enter the price for " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice;
        cout << "Please the amount sold of " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
         cin >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
    }

    //Good idea to initialize it before accessing iBestSeller.iSold
    iBestSeller = stockRecords[0];

    //This loop is only for determining the best seller
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {
        if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller.iSold) {
            iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
        }
    }

    //output the results 1 time
    cout << "biggest seller= " << iBestSeller.sName << " "
     << iBestSeller.fPrice << " " << iBestSeller.iSold << endl;



    //_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity, I kept it all separated.  In reality, there is no reason that you cannot combine the loop for input and loop to determine the best seller:

```
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
{
    cout << "Please enter stock name: ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName;
    cout << "Please enter the price for " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice;
    cout << "Please the amount sold of " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
    cin >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;


    if (iCount == 0)
    {  // will now need brackets
        iBestSeller = stockRecords[0];
        iWorstSeller = stockRecords[0];   // added
    }
    else if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller.iSold)
        iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
    //Added 
    else if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold < iWorstSeller.iSold)
        iWorstSeller = stockRecords[iCount];

}
```

Comment: thats great, thankyou for helping, i also need to do same with the worse seller(amongst other things) would it work if it did same but just in reverse?

Comment: Exactly.  Simply changing the `>` to `<` will give you the worst seller.  If you want both, just create another instance of `Stock` (`iWorstSeller`?) and initialize it the same way you initialize `iBestSeller` and run the opposing test within the same loop. I have editted the last bit of code in the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks alot Jason, much appreiciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for your help everyone, I managed to finish my program, with the other extra features it needed, Im very greatful for your help, next I need to learn vectors and pointers, so I may be back!!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>


using namespace std;

struct Stock//structure where items of stock and their price and amount sold are held
{
    string sName = "";
    float fPrice = 0;
    int iSold = 0;
};

int main()
{

    int iDiffSold = 0;// various varibles are named
    float fTotalSales = 0, fOpCost = 0, fTax = 0, fProfit = 0, fSalesWarning = 0;


    Stock iBestSeller{};// using stock types instead of ints
    Stock iWorseSeller{};


    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << "\n";//welcome mesage
    cout << "|            Hello, Welcome to the Program.                 |" << "\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << "\n";
    Stock stockRecords[5];

    //loop here for the input of 5 records
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter the name for the item of stock: ";
        cin >> stockRecords[iCount].sName;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the price for " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
        cin >> stockRecords[iCount].fPrice;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the amount sold of " << 
stockRecords[iCount].sName << ": ";
        cin >> stockRecords[iCount].iSold;
    }

    system("cls");

    // initialize iBestSeller
    iBestSeller = stockRecords[0];

    //This loop is for determining the best seller
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {
        if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold > iBestSeller.iSold) {
            iBestSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
        }
    }

    //output the best seller results
    cout << "\nbiggest seller= " << iBestSeller.sName << " it's selling price is "
    << iBestSeller.fPrice << " and " << iBestSeller.iSold << " item were sold" << endl;

    // initialize iWorseSeller
   iWorseSeller = stockRecords[0];

    //This loop is for determining the worse seller
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {
        if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold < iWorseSeller.iSold) {
            iWorseSeller = stockRecords[iCount];
        }
    }

    //output the worse seller results
    cout << "\nWorse seller= " << iWorseSeller.sName << " it's selling price is "
    << iWorseSeller.fPrice << " and  " << iWorseSeller.iSold << " items were sold" << endl;


    iDiffSold = iBestSeller.iSold - iWorseSeller.iSold;//this works out the difference between the most and least items sold

    cout << "\nThe difference between the amount of the most sold item and the least is " << iDiffSold << "\n" ;//outputs difference



    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++) {

        fTotalSales = fTotalSales + (stockRecords[iCount].iSold * stockRecords[iCount].fPrice);//this for loop finds the total price of all the items sold

    }

    cout << "\nThe total price of all the items sold is: " << fTotalSales << "\n";//outputs total

    fOpCost = fTotalSales / 2;//works out operational costs

    cout << "\nThe price of operational costs is: " << fOpCost << "\n";//outputs operational cost

    fTax = fTotalSales * .2;//works out tax due

    cout << "\nThe tax you will owe for these sales will be: " << fTax << "\n";//outputs tax due

    fProfit = fTotalSales - fOpCost - fTax;//works out profit

    cout << "\nThis will leave you a profit of: " << fProfit << "\n";//outputs profit

    fSalesWarning = fTotalSales * .005;//this line and the loops below work out and output the five percent of sales warning(if one is due)

    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
    {
        if (stockRecords[iCount].iSold * stockRecords[iCount].fPrice <= fSalesWarning)
        {
            cout << "\nWARNING! The item " << stockRecords[iCount].sName << " has sales that constitute 5% of sales or less";
        }
    }
      _getch();
    return 0;
}
```